# Не могу запустить тесты junit4 через консоль Linux

Tags: java, linux, junit

Написал тесты на junit4 с помощью intellij idea.

[image: Вот дерево тестов]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше запускал тесты через intellij idea, теперь задача стоит в том, чтобы тесты запускались через консоль в Linux Mint.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: `$ java -cp /home/ruslan/Programms/junit-4.9b3.jar:/home/ruslan/IdeaProjects/AllTests/src/test/java/Accounting/Journal/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore          IdeaProjects.AllTests.src.test.java.Accounting.FirstTimeLogin` - Выдает следующее: 
JUnit version 4.9b3
Could not find class: IdeaProjects.AllTests.src.test.java.Accounting.FirstTimeLogin

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)

Comment: А если пишу так: `$ java -cp .:/home/ruslan/Programms/junit-4.9b3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore FirstTimeLogin` то пишет: `JUnit version 4.9b3
Could not find class: FirstTimeLogin

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
`